# Be notified VS get notified

Tags: meaning, word-choice

when wanting to inform someone of some future event, in which way would you say it, and what are the differences, if any?

- (you will) **be notified** (...)
- (you will) **get notified** (...)

Answer (score 0):

Short version: Go with "be."

"Get" there is functioning as "become," rather than the more obvious definition of "receive." You might want to consider something closer to receive, though. Or maybe even swap out the passive voice to something like "We will notify you." Passive voice isn't wrong, but it is wordier and less direct.

Comment: In everyday English, _get_ is more common than _be_ to form the passive. In formal contexts, _be_ is preferred.

Comment: I am not a fan of passive voice, since "we will..." introduces irrelevant information which is the party which sends the information. who is this mysterious "we". maybe it's a computer. maybe it's a single person. this information is irrelevant to the person who should be informed of something, IMHO...

Comment: "We will" makes it active voice, rather than passive. Passive voice is a construction where the actor is omitted. It's great when you're trying to avoid giving anyone credit/blame for the action.